# Bootstrap 3.0 Responsive Menue Bar toggling issues..when increase content in menue bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, menubar

hi i have very serious problem in menubar. i am using bootstrap 3. menu bar is not toggling properly when reduce the size of browser window.i have 9 menue items with png icons.

i am putting my code here

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <!--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">--><!--temporary added-->

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/todoBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;ToDo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/dineBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dining</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/shopBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Shooping</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/todoBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;NightLife</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/fashionBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/bodyBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Body&Mind </a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/eventBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/exclusiveBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Exclusive</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/tarvelBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Travel</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--</div>--><!--new div-->
        </div>
```

again:: menu is not toggling properly because my content in menue is increase plz help me how i will manage in  bootsrap 3.0.

plz help me this is request to all of you

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It's got nothing to do with your content increasing, navbars in bootstrap have `<nav></nav>` tags around them which you missed and the button to toggle on smaller viewport, here's the complete navbar with your menu-links:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="navbar1">
            <!--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">--><!--temporary added-->

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/todoBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;ToDo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/dineBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dining</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/shopBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Shooping</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/todoBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;NightLife</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/fashionBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/bodyBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Body&Mind </a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/eventBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/exclusiveBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Exclusive</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/tarvelBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Travel</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--</div>--><!--new div-->
   </div>
</nav>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/iD8vTOw5p1)**

Comment: i have that code but the problem with this code is this menu bar is floating on the left side and there is empty space on right side i want to make mega menu bar in which each menu item has equal width and all menu item occupies all <UL> width mean no empty space is left behind

Comment: @kashifkhan So you need it to be centered with no space left on either side?

Comment: yes i want it to be full  on both side if some one has sample code must share with me

Comment: Are you aware that there are proper third-party megamenu plugins for Bootstrap?

Comment: no i am not aware about that if u have any link of example please share with me